# Python Seaborn: How can one obtain a box plot (box and whisker plot) for the non-diagonal variable pairs in a pairplot()?

Tags: python, visualization

I tried using kind="box" but am not sure if that works. For the example I tried, I got blank subfigures in the non-diagonal parts of the PairGrid.

Edit: Details.

The function I am trying to use is [`seaborn.pairplot`](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html). As mentioned in the link, by default, this function will create a grid of Axes such that each variable in the `data` parameter will be shared in the y-axis across a single row and in the x-axis across a single column. The diagonal Axes are treated differently, drawing a plot to show the univariate distribution of the data for the variable in that column.

I am looking for a way to make sure that the `kind` parameter leads to a box plot ([`seaborn.boxplot`](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html)) for the non-diagonal parts of the PairGrid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This wouldn't be possible in seaborn without changing the [source code](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/master/seaborn/linearmodels.py).

pairplot is designed with only two options for the non-diagonal plots: scatter or reg.  This can be seen in the source code:

```
if kind == "scatter":
    plot_kws.setdefault("edgecolor", "white")
    plotter(plt.scatter, **plot_kws)
elif kind == "reg":
    plotter(regplot, **plot_kws)
```

One option would be copy the source code and create a function similar to pairplot, but with the ability to plot boxplots.